# Embeded Tomcat 9 to execute @PostConstruct

Tags: java, myfaces, tomcat9

I am creating an executable jar where using Jsf myfaces 2.3 with Tomcat 9 embedded, so when i execute the jar it will read a war file and deploy it on the embedded server, Its reading the bean and displaying contents correctly.
However tomcat seems not executing @PostConstruct annotation.

For example: I have the following in a bean:

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("init bean called..........");
    }
```

But its not executing the void bean the bean is called.

I have included javax.annotation-api-1.3.2 jar in the WEB-INF\Lib folder.

```
String contextPath = "/Test";     
        String warFilePath = "D:\\Test\\embedded\\Test.war";
StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, warFilePath);
((StandardJarScanner) ctx.getJarScanner()).setScanAllDirectories(true);
((StandardJarScanner) ctx.getJarScanner()).setScanAllFiles(true);
((StandardJarScanner) ctx.getJarScanner()).setScanClassPath(true);

tomcat.start();
tomcat.getServer().await();
```

No error messages... on the console. Simply not executing @PostConstruct init void. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: since PostConstruct gets called after object creation of the class. Can you please check whether the object is created for the class having the PostConstruct method.
If you have a constructor in a class, check it by putting logs inside the constructor.

Comment: yes, the object is created. i can execute other method and other variables in that class.

Comment: Which CDI implementation did you choose to use? [MyFaces 2.3 requires CDI 2.0](https://myfaces.apache.org/core23/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.. simply need to enable naming.

```
tomcat.enableNaming();
```

in my main void:

```
Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setBaseDir("temp");
tomcat.setPort(8080);
tomcat.enableNaming();
tomcat.getConnector(); // Tomcat 9 we need to get the connector. it not by default.

String contextPath = "/Test";     
String warFilePath = "D:\\Test\\embedded\\Test.war";

tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(".");
StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, warFilePath);
((StandardJarScanner) ctx.getJarScanner()).setScanAllDirectories(true);
((StandardJarScanner) ctx.getJarScanner()).setScanAllFiles(true);
((StandardJarScanner) ctx.getJarScanner()).setScanClassPath(true);

tomcat.start();
tomcat.getServer().await();
```